# how to solve Class 'App\Events\Event' not found in laravel 5.3 on extends event class

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

[image: Error file image]

```
class NewMessage extends Event{

}
//Using this i am getting error visible in image.
```

Comment: Add use App\Events\Event; after namespace App\Events;

Comment: use App\Event\Event add before class

Comment: <?php namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewMessage extends Event
{

}

Comment: Where did you read that you have to extend `Event` class? The docs never mention that. When you extend something, that class has to exist. If you get that message, then `App\Events\Event` DOES NOT exist - which you could have determined on your own. Read the docs. Always. -1 for lack of effort.

Answer (score 5):

You need just delete `extends Event` from your code

Comment: People typically use `extends` for a reason. This is not a very helpful answer.

Comment: @N.B. Maybe. There used to be an `App\Events\Event` abstract class that shipped with Laravel by default. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/05235ee6bff52926b266ce0a295f3f2fc35451e0/app/Events/Event.php

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, but it's changed in 5.3 and OP uses 5.3. There's no base `Events` class any more or any sort of interface for it.

Comment: @N.B. If they're an upgrade to 5.3 instead of a greenfield install, it may be there. First step would be OP looking to see if `app/Events/Event.php` exists. Possible they're just looking at outdated tuts blindly, but other scenarios are possible.

Comment: @ceejayoz well had that class been there, OP wouldn't be getting the error. Relating to 5.3, this answer is correct but it really needs a few words more to explain why it's correct for that version of Laravel. It's a case of not reading the **correct** manual / running to SO without doing any prior discovery (this is really basic IMO).